# Listing the authors of a web site according to Google?

Tags: google-plus

Google allows to its users to [list](http://plus.google.com/me/about/edit/co) which web sites the contribute to. If the web-site also links to the G+ profile of the person with ?rel=authors then Google can show the avatar of the person on Google search results. [See](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1408986?hl=en) further explanations.

Is there a way to get the list of people who added a web site to their "contribute to" list?
A manual search on Google or an API?

Answer (score 0):

The [`People.search`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) REST API method does not appear to support searching data from the contributor fields. You can [try it yourself here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.search). The data is exposed in the response from the [`People.get`](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) method, but is not apparently part of the full text search.